# how to make a lineplot representing the annual number of songs by year

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, line-plot

It's such a beginer question but I cant find to solve it. I am working on Jupyter notebook and I want to plot a line graph representing the annual number of songs since 1921. I have no issue doing it as a bar graph but as soon as I try to do it as linpeplot I cant since I dont have a column name for the index. I need that exact plot but as a lineplot.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('https://storage.googleapis.com/introduction-to-data-science/spotify-dataset.csv')

plt.figure(figsize = (40,15))
sns.countplot(data=df, x="year")
```

Comment: What happens to the program output when you try to do this?

Comment: I get a barplot but not a line plot

Comment: 'plt.figure(figsize = (40,15)) sns.plot.line(data=df, x="year")' try this

Answer (score 1):

Does this give you what you are looking for?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('https://storage.googleapis.com/introduction-to-data-science/spotify-dataset.csv')
df["count"] = 1
df_grouped = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(["year"]).count().loc[:, "count"])
plt.figure(figsize = (40,15))
sns.lineplot(data=df_grouped, x="year", y="count")
```

`sns.lineplot()` takes a second argument, the `y` which you would have to set up before.

Comment: it worked perfectly thank you very much! In fact the key as you said was just to creat the column count.